# Resolve VSCode Errors and Typescript 4.4+ Discrepancy

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsc

Typescript 4.4 introduced the `useUnknownInCatchVariables` option that is enabled by default when tsconfig has `strict` enabled. This option changes the type of e in catch from any to unknown. Consider the following code:

```
// index.ts
function example() {
  try {
    throw new Error('Foo')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.stack)
  }
}

example()
```

VSCode sees the above code as valid and looks like the following on highlight (note how it sees the e as type any):
[image]

There are no highlighted errors. However tsc generates:

```
index.ts:5:17 - error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
32     console.log(e.stack);
```

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["index.ts"],
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Recommended"
}
```

How do I resolve this inconsistency and utilize the new `useUnknownInCatchVariables` while seeing errors in VSCode?

Comment: The comment on your code says that the file name is `index.js`, not `index.ts`, are you in a ts file? [Works fine in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useUnknownInCatchVariables=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgEpEBvAKEUSgCcBPMyq6gCxrgHdExkuBRGuxoEA5ADE4cEUSYBfRBHRQILRAWQkKzBQgDOcfADpccAObrDuqOggBrGVVnkn5NFjyEiQA)

Comment: @Owl Whoops just a question typo. The actual code is in index.ts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much messing around it ended up being simple. Didn't think about it before but updating VSCode to the latest version fixed the issue.